# How to call web service using client certificates / mutual authentication?

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, certificate, webservice-client

I'm building a web service client using vb .net. The web service is secured with ssl, basic authentication and also requires client certificates. So I created a web reference in Visual Studio and provided the credentials:

```
Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("usr", "passwd")
Dim proxy As New SimpleFromLocal.simple
proxy.Credentials = cred

Console.WriteLine(proxy.helloWorld())
```

This works as expected, as long as I turn off mutual authentication on the server side.
I added a client certificate like this:

```
Dim cert As X509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certFile)
proxy.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
```

The certificate is loaded, but the web service call fails. I could post the exception, but it is in german, which is an issue on its own. It basically says: Authentication failed, because the remote site closed the connection.
I tried debugging the ssl handshake on the server side and it looks like the client certificate is not transmitted.

So what am I missing here? Is it required to install the client certificate on the local machine?

**Edit:** The error thrown:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. 
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at CCClient.SimpleFromLocal.simple.helloWorld() in C:\TP\CCClient\CCClient\Web References\SimpleFromLocal\Reference.vb:Zeile 90.
at CCClient.Module1.clientWithProxy(NetworkCredential cred, String certFile)
in C:\TP\CCClient\CCClient\Module1.vb:Zeile 53.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally!

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473494/client-certs-without-using-the-keystore) made me try using `X509Certificate2` (note the **2** in class name). I used it with a PKCS#12 keystore only containing a single certificate. So here is what I did:

**Create the keystore file**

I used Java's [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) for this. After creating a self-signed certificate, it needed to be exported to the desired format:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks \
        -srcstoretype JKS \
        -destkeystore keystore.pfx \
        -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Note: Exporting the certificate to a file and using it directly does not work.

**Add client certificate to proxy**

```
Dim proxy As New SimpleFromLocal.simple
Dim cred As New NetworkCredential("usr", "passwd")
Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(certFile, "passwd")
proxy.Credentials = cred
proxy.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)

Console.WriteLine(proxy.helloWorld())
```

And that's it. The same setup fails using `X509Certificate` for whatever reasons.

Comment: In .NET sometimes the handshaking need to be specified
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;  //used SSL3 to avoid handshake issues